# IIS Url rewrite does not work

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

I have a problem with iis rewrite module. I googled it and search it too much but my problem is stil exists.

I have two rewrite rules, first one redirect any http request to https equivalant and the second one redirect some specific pages to a some other page.

the http requests successfully redirects to https but the second rule does not work properly.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>      
    <rule name="redirect special page" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)MySite.com/accountTransactions" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="MySite.com/404.html" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm using IIS 8, windows server 2012 R2.

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The `match url` should not contain the domain name, but path

```
<match url="^accountTransactions" />
```

See http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

If you need to match a path under specific domain (when your site has multiple domain names) then you should add condition for {HTTP_HOST}

```
<conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" type="Pattern" pattern="^www\.mysite\.com$"> 
</conditions>
```